# Android java set app permissions dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Is it possible to set `android` app `permission` dynamically in `java`, usually it is set in `AndroidManifest.xml`. But what I want to do is giving my users a choice of what `permissions` they want my app to give.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Pretty sure it is not allowed to gain permission on run time.

Comment: So it is not possible disallow permissions that the app already uses?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not currently possible. Up through Android Lollipop, permissions must be explicitly requested in the app's manifest and must be collectively all granted or denied (not installing the app) by the user at install time.

Android M, however, is changing this. As of Android M, permissions will be granted at runtime instead of at install time, allowing you to give users more control over which permissions they allow your app to use.

See the [Android M runtime permissions documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html) for more detail.

Comment: Hmm. What about [addPermission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#addPermission%28android.content.pm.PermissionInfo%29)? And ["uses-permission"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestUsesPermission)?

Comment: Thanks really helpful documentation!

Comment: @HannoBinder `<uses-permission>` is not runtime- that is how you currently request permissions that will be granted at install time. `addPermission()` is for defining new permissions, not for requesting existing permissions.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it's not possible http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

`Android has no mechanism for granting permissions dynamically (at run-time) because it complicates the user experience to the detriment of security.`

Things may change in new android M release

Answer (score 0):

Nope. App's permissions are declared in AndroidManifest.xml, which is used to tell Android system what permissions are required. App installer will show all permissions to help user judge the app is good or bad.

Thing about that if an malicious app require nothing at install-time and require camera permission at run-time dynamically

Comment: I can see the problem in that, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It would be against Android policy . The application has or not has the permissions for doing something . It can be a security problem if you can think of it.
It is possible no issue but in mid of app if not get then chances of getting crash in your app...